# Constrain to check increasing index in yang model

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

i am working on a yang model. In this i need to have a list in which one leaf key (index) should be always in increasing order. I need to add constrain for this in yang model. any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `must` constraint that ensures this.

```
module increasing-index {
    namespace "org:example:increasing-index";
    prefix "oeii";

    list item {    
        must "not(preceding-sibling::item) or preceding-sibling::item/index < index" {
            error-message "Items must be ordered by index value in increasing order.";
        }
        key index;
        leaf index {
            type uint32;             
        }
    }
}
```

The condition `not(preceding-sibling::item) or preceding-sibling::item/index < index` above means the following: there are either no preceding items or there are no preceding items that have an index value which is less than the index value of current item. The condition must be satisfied by every item in the list.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <oeii:item xmlns:oeii="org:example:increasing-index">
    <oeii:index>12</oeii:index>
  </oeii:item>
  <oeii:item xmlns:oeii="org:example:increasing-index">
    <oeii:index>13</oeii:index>
  </oeii:item>
  <oeii:item xmlns:oeii="org:example:increasing-index">
    <oeii:index>10</oeii:index>
  </oeii:item>
</config>
```

```
Error at (9:3): failed assert at "/nc:config/oeii:item": Items must be ordered by index value in increasing order.
```

Note: if the list is `ordered-by system` (which is default), the device which implements the model could order list entries in any way it pleases - even without such a constraint it could order by increasing index values, so perhaps such a constraint is redundant semantic sugar.

Comment: I did tried your yang module, but it's giving me error as "Unexpected character(s) 'p' (preceding-sibli)" . Do i need to import any other module to support this. I tried with yanglint tool.

Comment: @J.K.Mahapatra, my example is pure valid YANG code and should compile/validate in any RFC6020/RFC7950 compliant tool.